# i am learning django websocket everything is working fine except for my JS function in HTML file

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-channels

I am working on django websocket and creating an Echo app but i don't know why i am getting this error[image]

**Here is my html code**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Notifier</title>
    <script src="{% static '/channels/js/websocketbridge.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
 <body>

 <h1>Notifier</h1>
 <script>
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   const webSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge();
   webSocketBridge.connect('/ws/');
   webSocketBridge.listen(function(action, stream) {
    console.log("RESPONSE:", action, stream);
  })
  document.ws = webSocketBridge; /* for debugging */
  })
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

**This is my views.py**

```
 from django.views.generic import TemplateView


 class HomeView(TemplateView):
     template_name = "home.html"
```

**This is my routing.py**

```
   from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
   from django.urls import path
   from notifier.consumers import EchoConsumer

    application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
         "websocket": URLRouter([
         path("ws/", EchoConsumer),
     ])
   })
```

**Tihs is my counsumers.py**

```
 from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer


class EchoConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
   async def websocket_connect(self, event):
       await self.send({
          "type": "websocket.accept"
      })

  async def websocket_receive(self, event):
      # Echo the same received payload
      await self.send({
          "type": "websocket.send",
          "text": event["text"]
      })
```

Guide me with my mistake where and what i am doing wrong in this whole system i do not find any solution on internet i would expect this code to run properly and do an Echo on my browser console.

Comment: The error is just that your js file **websocketbridge.js** cannot be found. I'm assuming this is on your development machine with DEBUG=True, running the Django development server? Is the path **/js/websocketbridge.js** inside the **static** directory of one of your apps? If **static** is not inside one of your apps, e.g. in the main project folder, have you added it to `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your settings.py? Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/).

Comment: Please provide a valid solution i gave you every piece of code and you are just making judgements

Comment: i added the js script in static folder so not it is only showing me one error that is channels is not defined.

Comment: No. There are 2 errors. The first one is a 404 that it cannot load the script. The second one is that `channels` is not defined, which is obvious if it didn’t load the js file.

Comment: JS file started working but now in js it is showing channels not defines

Comment: Then you should update your question. Also please tell us which exact (pip) package you're using and where websocketbridge.js comes from.